# How do you write "Amy" and "Amelia" in Gallifreyan?

Tags: doctor-who, translation

How are the words Amy and Amelia written in Gallifreyan?

I found something like that, but I'm not able to verify its correctness.

[image]

Or

[image]

This will be the name of my daughter, so this will be printed on the wall

Comment: Do you want a translation or a transliteration?

Comment: Both would be awesome.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you aware of the difference? One would likely prove different results to the other. A translation may also not be possible

Comment: Not even the TARDIS can translate it and you expect us to?

Comment: I don't know what to expect, when you asked for translation or transliteration. But I'm curious about the answer. I found some pictures but they are differently to each other.

Comment: A translation would be Amy translated and then could be written in either English or Gallifreyan (I believe you’re looking for circular Gallifreyan), I.e., a Gallifreyan word written in English _or_ Gallifreyan. A transliteration would be taking the letters “A”, “m” and “y” and composing a word of the three English letters written in their Gallifreyan counterpart. It would be an English word written in Gallifreyan.

Comment: Don't forget there is a dedicated [conlang.se] site!

Comment: How do you write “Amy” and “Amelia” in Gallifreyan? *Very carefully.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no canonical Circular Gallifreyan. However, you are not totally out of luck. In 2011 a fan by the name of Loren Sherman created a system that has been used by the show on official merchandise including a [comic](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/11DY3_4).

[image]

> Gallifreyan is the fictional language of the Time Lords, from the TV show Doctor Who. On the show, it's usually just random circles. I'm not affiliated with Doctor Who or the BBC, but back in 2011, I created a "Gallifreyan" writing system. It somehow got really popular among fans and eventually made its way onto the show.
>   <sub>[Sherman's Website](http://shermansplanet.com/gallifreyan.html)</sub>

His system is based on the Gallifreyan depicted in the show. But would not be able to decode any of the Gallifreyan shown.

> All forms of Gallifreyan [...] are based off of Gallifreyan in the show Doctor Who. They're fan made however, because the Gallifreyan in the show cannot be decoded because there is simply nothing to decode.
>   <sub>[Omniglot | Sherman's Gallifreyan](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/shermansgallifreyan.htm)</sub>

> **What does the Gallifreyan in this episode translate to?**
>   Nothing, unfortunately. In Doctor Who, they just draw random cool-looking circles for Gallifreyan.
>   <sub>[A Guide to the Gallifreyan Alphabet - Loren Sherman](http://shermansplanet.com/gallifreyan/guide.pdf)</sub>

He wrote up all the rules into a guide you can view [here](http://shermansplanet.com/gallifreyan/guide.pdf). And another fan took these rules, and wrote a translator you can see [here](https://adrian17.github.io/Gallifreyan/).

Using this, your first image is close to what the translator outputs for "Amy". But here are both.

**Amy**

[image: "Amy" in Circular Gallifreyan]

**Amelia**

[image: "Amelia" in Circular Gallifreyan]

Comment: Well, I stand corrected!! +1 and can't wait to play with this thing.

Comment: Cool! Small suggestion: maybe it would be neat to include the name meaning translated to Gallifreyan? According to Wikipedia it means "Industrious" although other sources list it as "Defender".

Comment: If you want to take @ConjureFlyingFoxes' suggestion, [Amelia](http://www.behindthename.com/name/amelia) comes from a Germanic name element *amal* which meant "work" (whence the "industrious" interpretation); [Amy](http://www.behindthename.com/name/amy) arose as an independent name in England as a variant of the Old French name *Amée* which ultimately derived from Latin *Amatus* for "loved" (the modern French word for "loved", *aimée*, is sometimes used today as an alternate spelling for Amy). So Galifreyan for either "loved/beloved" or "work" would be reasonable "translations" of the names.

Comment: @tilley31 these are transliteration, not translations, if I’ve read correctly

Comment: @1006a After your comment, my tough was that a reasonable "translations" would be the origin word "amal" and not the translation in English as "work". Other thoughts?

Comment: @dh_cgn I think the transliterations of the actual names, in amflare's answer, are a good choice. To get a real "translation" you'd need to know the word in (spoken) Gallifreyan, and then figure out how to write that in (written) Gallifreyan; unfortunately I don't think we actually know much of anything about spoken Gallifreyan, but if we did I'd think basic words like "work" would be easiest to find. The next-closest thing to a translation, I think, would be a transliteration of the "meaning" of the word in whatever language you expect your daughter to speak. I probably...(cont.)

Comment: … wouldn't choose a transliteration of “amal” because that’s just a piece of the name—it was also an element in other names, like Amalasuintha (“work” + “strong”; eventually became Millicent) Amalbert (“work” + “bright”) and Amalric (“work” + “power”; a possible ancestor of Emmerich and thence names like Emery and Emmerson and Emmeline), and Amelia’s direct ancestor was potentially a nickname for any of those (like how Ellie can be short for Eleanor, Elizabeth, Elpheba, or Elora Danan). Maybe play around with the generator, plugging in variations, and just go with the image that you like best.